# Is there a way to import a view grid into a Carousel

Tags: 7, views

Hi i have created grid view of a content type coupon which has a logo,description and download button and i'm wondering is there a way to import that view into a Carousel so it can display a grid of 9 coupons and when i hit next it displays another set of 9.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you got so far?

Comment: So far i created my grid view of coupons

Comment: Which modules are you using?

Comment: Hi, Mark. Not much to go on here. Help us help you by providing more info. Are you using JCarousel library? What modules have you installed in addition to Views, if any?

Comment: I'm using Views Slideshow module and it's dependency modules i have installed Views Slideshow Cycle module

Comment: I don't know how helpful was that or if it was..but its where i am

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [jCarousel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) which has great integration with views module.

This tutorial might help you as well - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEMBVGBFskE